# android:layout_width="Xdp" not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple layout. it's a button with the following code:

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="100dip"
                android:text="Y" />
```

I run it on a two devices, one is smaller then the other. i noticed no change in size of button. I though when using dip, the view's size changes according to the screen size. 
Am i wrong or what?

Comment: I think the dip==dp no difference between them! you can check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: Yes @MaheeraJazi-newaccount- i know. but i see no difference in the button. button that is displayed on the larger screen should be large as compared to the button that is displayed on the smaller screen. right ??

Comment: No cause you use fixed size ,, you can use (FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, MATCH_PARENT) for the layout_width & layout_height to see the change on Button size !!  ex. android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: I want button to adjust the size automatically according to screen size. ex. When i run the app on smaller screen i see a button but when i run the app on larger screen i want to see that button a little bit bigger.

Comment: You have defined size in dip and by reference of official documentation, it should adjust the size itself on different screens. Would you please upload a screenshot so everybody can see how exactly it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If you had set that in pixels, size would change because of different screen densities.  `dp` are used to overcome this situation, so that size is fixed.

If you want your dimensions to change proportionally with the screen size, I think you should use `android:weight=` inside a `LinearLayout`. I.e.:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:weightSum="3"
     ... >

    <Button
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Button 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In this case, `Button 1` will always be 1/3 of the `LinearLayout` width, while `Button 2` will always be 2/3 .

See this pretty popular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2025282/4288782).

Comment: i want my button to resize it self according to screen size. can't be it a requirement? it is not a good practice to do??

Comment: It's up to you and how you want your UI to be. If you want to, you need to use `0dp` and `layout_weight` as shown. I can say that hardcoding values (like `100dp`, as in your example) might be bad practice in some cases.

Comment: but there is an image view in my layout. actually that's the profile picture. so how can i handle it on different screen sizes??

Comment: A picture should probably keep its ratio, so LinearLayout is not a good idea. You should put different sized pictures in different folders of your project - take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)